# The definition of covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to understand the notion of covariant derivative defined on a vector bundle say $E \longrightarrow M $, but I didn't understand what is meant by  $(Xf)s$ in the condition which says: $\nabla_{X}(fs)= (Xf)s + f \nabla_{X}s$, where $f \in C^\infty(M), X \in \Gamma (M) $ and $s \in \Gamma (M,E)$.

Since $Xf \in  \Gamma (M) $ and $s \in \Gamma (M,E)$, what I precisely want to know is what is the product defined between the spaces $\Gamma (M) $ and $\Gamma (M,E)$?

I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: $Xf$ is a smooth function on $M$ defined by $p \mapsto (Xf)(p)=X_pf \in \mathbb{R}$. So $(Xf)s$ is another smooth section on the bundle. Moreover $\Gamma(M,E)$ is a module over $C^{\infty}(M)$.

Comment: Oh I see!, I thought it's a section  of the tangent bundle defined by $p \longmapsto ( Xf)(p):= f(p)X(p) \in T_pM$. Thank you @si Kucing for correcting me.

Comment: Your welcome. $Xf$ and $fX$ are different.